# Nonlinear constitutive state equation

Tags: acoustics, ideal-gas, non-linear-systems, thermodynamics

Between the [Tait equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tait_equation), and the B/A [type of equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_acoustics), which one is better suited to approximate the [isentropic equation of state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process#Derivation_of_the_isentropic_relations)?

Why B/A type is mostly used in nonlinear acoustics?

Comment: Thanks for the edit New_new_newbie. It looks much better now.

Comment: Further suggestion - What's B/A is not obvious (to me, at least). Maybe you could edit the post further and describe/link-to what it means. That will improve the odds of the question being answered :)

Comment: Hope its clear now.

Comment: How practical is it to use an isentropic equation of state for nonlinear acoustics?  Think of a shock wave.  By definition, such phenomena must increase entropy.  Am I missing something from your question?